# How to scan in a word using getchar()

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, getchar

I am currently writing a program and I want to scan in a word and save it in an array of chars. How am I able to scan in a word from the user input to an array using getchar(). Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `scanf` to read a string, instead of reading one character at a time whit `getchar`?

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Have you never used [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) before? There must be tens of thousands (or more) of examples on how to use it if you just search a little.

Comment: Suggest posting your program.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this if you must use `getchar()`

```
char array[SOME_GOOD_SIZE] ;
int i = 0 , ch;
while( ( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' ) && ( ch != ' ' ) && ( i < ( SOME_GOOD_SIZE - 1 ) ) )
   array[i++]=ch;
array[i]='\0';
```

or simply use [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) ( Recommended ) like

```
char array[SOME_GOOD_SIZE];
scanf("%s",array);
```

Comment: Prevent buffer overflows in both the codes. You earn my +1 if you do that. And the `getchar` code is wrong. It won't work. Also, `ch` should be an `int`

Comment: Forgot about that, Thanks for notifying @CoolGuy, Will this edit do?

Comment: @CoolGuy , what do you mean by `getchar` code is wrong?

Comment: Hint : `( ch = getchar() != '\n' )` Which one will execute first? `!=` or `=`?

Comment: @CoolGuy, Why must `ch` be an int, is there some specific reason?

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`. `char` , when declared, can be `unsigned` or `signed`(implementation defined). If `char` is `unsigned`, and when `getchar()` returns `EOF`, it will wrap around, causing confusion as to why `EOF` is not encountered.

Comment: @CoolGuy , never knew about that, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char word[100] = { 0 };
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("%s", word);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Scanf is the best option (in my opinion) to read the String from keyboard, but maybe he also wanted the version with getchar().

Answer (score 0):

To scan a "word" typically involves 5 steps:

1. (Optionally) Scan and toss all leading white-space.
2. Scan and save some finite number of non-white-space.
3. Continue until `EOF` or white-space character encountered - put last character back.
4. Append a `'\0'` to the "word".
5. Reports results.

.

```
// Return count of `char` saved into word.  -1 on EOF.
int JG_ReadWord(char *buffer, int size) {
  int ch;
  while (isspace(ch = getchar());
  int len;
  for (len=0; len < size-1 && ch != EOF && !isspace(ch); len++) {
    buffer[len] = ch;
    ch = getchar(); 
  }
  buffer[len] = '\0';
  unget(ch, stdin);
  if (len == 0 && ch == EOF) return -1;
  return len; 
}
```

This is similar to

```
char buffer[80];
// retval = 1 (word of length > 0), or EOF.
int retval = scanf("%79s", buffer);
```